# I moved my armature and now my animation won't play

Tags: animation, armature

I made an animation, it worked fine and I have 2 other objects animated in the scene.

But when I made my scene I moved the first two objects to their new destination, and their animations continued as I made them but in their new location. I moved my main character to the new location (they were all starting in the same location and moved to almost the same new location).

When I moved my main character all his animations stopped.

You can see in the image all the keyframes are still there and all the f-curves are still there. The animation just doesn't play on the character anymore.

(Super frustrating probably some easy beginner mistake would love any help on getting my character to move again.)

I have tried:

- Restarting blender
- Copying the model and armature and linking animation data
- All transforms are applied
- Re-assigning bone weights
- Making a new animation to test rig (it makes new animations but doesn't play the old one)

[image]

Comment: without seeing any of your rigging settings - we can just guess. So please provide your blend file so we can check it out. thx.